# highcharts will not render to my div

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, highcharts

I'm trying to render a highchart demo to a backbone.js widget.

I'm trying to include the [HighChart Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) in my widget, The template generates, and everything but HighCharts is working. I suspect that highchart has a problem rendering to a div that has not been put on the DOM yet, since I'm able to add the chart afterwards.

Does anyont have any ideas as to how it would be posible to add the chart-widget to the tree during the render cycle?

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {},

    render:function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        var chart = $("#chart", this.el)[0];
        this.renderChart(chart);        
        return this;
    },

    renderChart: function(container) {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 21.63,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 11.94,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Chrome versions',
                        categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                            'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                        data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 7.15,
                    color: colors[3],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Safari versions',
                        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                        color: colors[3]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                        data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];


        // Build the data arrays
        var browserData = [];
        var versionsData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            // add browser data
            browserData.push({
                name: categories[i],
                y: data[i].y,
                color: data[i].color
            });

            // add version data
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
                var brightness = 0.2 - (j / data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
                versionsData.push({
                    name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                    y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                    color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
                });
            }
        }


        // Create the chart
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    shadow: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Browsers',
                data: browserData,
                size: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                    },
                    color: 'white',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                data: versionsData,
                innerSize: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

So far my best solution has been to have an event that is triggered and courses a post-render cycle.

This is in no way optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
render: function () {
    var element = this.el;
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    $("#chart").append(element);
    this.renderChart(element);        
    return this;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that $(this.el) might not be on the DOM yet.. It might be generated as a widget on some page and be added to the DOM later.. So rendering the chart will not work.

Comment: I get a DOM insertion error, which makes sense since I'm trying to insert the element into itself. Remember that the #chart in defined in the code generated by this.template(). Meaning that the lookup $('#chart') does not make sense since #chart is in $(this.el). and again, #charts might not have been added to the DOM yet, since it coult be a part of a larger widget.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are absolutely correct! if the render function is called, and the element i added to this.el before the chart is drawn, everything should work fine.